# How to Annotate an Array NonNull?

Tags: java, eclipse, non-nullable

I'm using **org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull** to add extra information for static null analysis.  I donn't know how to annotate arrays correctly:

1. How can I say that an array reference is non-null?
2. How can I say that an array consists of non-null elements?

I've tested:

```
    public static void test(@NonNull String[] a) {
        assert a != null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(null);
    }
```

However, Eclipse doesn't mark `test(null);` as wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you 're using Java 8, it looks as follows:

```
@NonNull Object [] o1;

o1    = null;           // OK
o1    = new Object[1];
o1[0] = null;           // NOT OK

Object @NonNull[] o2;

o2    = null;           // NOT OK
o2    = new Object[1];
o2[0] = null;           // OK
```

Answer (score 5):

> 1. How can I say that an array reference is non-null?

You should've put `@NonNull` *after* the type declaration (but *before* the array brackets), eg.,

```
public static void test(String @NonNull[] a) {
    assert a != null;
}
```

> 2. How can I say that an array consists of non-null elements?

Your original question has that.

EDIT: For [Java 8](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_type_annotations.htm) compatibility, the syntax had to be changed a little (modified above code accordingly).